# How should I escape?

Tags: php, html, escaping

its a simple logger function. I want to load an array to a DIV content:

```
document.getElementById('layout').innerHTML = '<?php foreach ($logs as $item) { echo str_replace(array('"',"'"), array ('&quot;','&#039;'), $item).'<hr />'; } ?>';
```

because $logs can contain HTML elements, but not quotes, since they would ruin the echoing. It should be OK, but Firefox say "malformed Unicode character sequence" and it doesnt displayed. Now what?

Comment: What does Firefox show as the source when you run it (ie, is the PHP being processed correctly)?

Comment: <span style=&quot;background-color:yellow;&quot;><i>Missing argument 3 for Upload::ID(), called in action_index.php on line 149 and defined</i></span>, in <span style=&quot;background-color:#40FF40;&quot;><b

Comment: Why the downvote from someone? I've upvoted to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

use [html entities](http://php.net/htmlentities) to translate your html code into safe sequencies

Comment: yea, but it then would spoil the < > characters too

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800454/php-no-good-escape) you may find answer to your question

Comment: I think you should prepare some `$output` before you setting innerHTML, and then just do, not looping

`document.getElementById('layout').innerHTML = '<?php echo $output ?>'`

Comment: and like I said, it spoils the < > html characters

Comment: it should change `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` so it SHOULD NOT spoil your html, or I don't understand you correctly..

Comment: but I want HTML elements to be survived. HTML is allowed

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it looks like you're trying to enter php code into your page using javascript. Javascript is client side, so if anything, you will get the full code, not the parsed code.

If you want the php to be run beforehand, so the actual code in your page will be a javascript that has the allready-parsed contents in it, you neet to make a string that contains the finished content AND add "'" for javascript to understand it.

This might look like this (haven't checked the foreach for you)

```
<?//this part is parsed before sending it to the client
   $conts = "'"; 
   foreach ($logs as $item) { 
        $conts .= str_replace(array('"',"'"), array ('&quot;','&#039;'), $item);
        $conts .= "<hr/>";
   }
   $conts .= "'";
?>
document.getElementById('layout').innerHTML = <? echo $conts ?>;
```